# Declare API in Azure APIM with client_id and client_secret

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, postman, apim

Our client has shared some API's. They have provided us `client_id`, `client_secret`. (I have 4 different pairs). I want to declare them in Azure APIM & create our dedicated credential which we can share with our customers. (corresponding to 4 pairs that can we create?)

Is this scenario possible in Azure?

- I created a instance in API management,
- I created API by importing swagger file.
- When I pass parameters and try to test it, I get below error:

> { "httpCode": "401", "httpMessage": "Unauthorized", "moreInformation":
> "Invalid client id or secret." } I am not getting where to add client
> id and secret shared by my client & create our dedicated credential
> which we can share with our customers.

Comment: Refer this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/authorizations-how-to-azure-ad

Answer (score 0):

I have enabled Authorization by enabling system managed identity for my APIM and In order to add the Authorization with Client Id and Client secret, ***I have referred this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/authorizations-how-to-azure-ad) like below:-***

According to your error code make sure the client ID and client secret shared by your client is correct, You can verify like below:-

**Client ID:-**

[image]

**Client Secret:-**

[image]

You need to have Authorization URL that you can ask from your client from the this section:-

[image]

**Client Credentials:-**

[image]

**For Authorization Code:-**

Select authorize endpoint like below and add it in Authorization URL:-

[image]

[image]

Click on Create after Authorization is created select Next and Click on Login with Azure Active Directory v1 and allow the access when prompted for browser login with your organizational account:-

[image]

**For ClientCredentials select the option below and click on Add members:-**

[image]

Click on complete the Authorization will be saved.

Now visit API in the left pane of APIM> Create new HTTP API like below:-

[image]

[image]

After creating this Operation > Add Inbound Policy like below:-

[image]

Test the API.

Comment: Hi Sidhesh, 

Thanks for your help but I already have client_id and client_secret received from my vendor alongwith API. 

Can I declare them in Azure APIM & create our dedicated credential which we can share with our customers. (corresponding to 2 pairs?) 

I can't directly share vendor's credentials with customer.
  {
    "name": "*****ES",
    "client_id": "*****54b",
    "client_secret": "***G6"
  },
  {
    "name": "****CONSULTING",
    "client_id": "*****3e97",
    "client_secret": "***kB4vP"
  },

Comment: Once you refer till step 3 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/authorizations-how-to-azure-ad#step-4-create-a-microsoft-graph-api-in-api-management-and-configure-a-policy You can refer this step and create an API with the inbound policy and authorization id set to step 2 and test this API. You can ask your customers to run this API directly as the Authorization is already done with client id and, client secret

Comment: Hi Siddhesh, I tried all the above steps and now I am getting new error "Azure AD JWT not present". But still I didn't understand 1 thing, API's given to me are already secured by Client ID & client secret (given by customer) which I didn't used anywhere. How does it still working then ?